# Pandas: Count values on a row basis

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a numeric DataFrame, for example:

```
x = np.array([[1,2,3],[-1,-1,1],[0,0,0]])
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['A','B','C'])
df

   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1 -1 -1  1
2  0  0  0
```

And I want to count, for each row, the number of positive values, negativa values and values equals to 0. I've been trying the following:

```
df['positive_count'] = df.apply(lambda row: (row > 0).sum(), axis = 1)
df['negative_count'] = df.apply(lambda row: (row < 0).sum(), axis = 1)
df['zero_count'] = df.apply(lambda row: (row == 0).sum(), axis = 1)
```

But I'm getting the following result, which is obviously incorrent

```
   A  B  C  positive_count  negative_count  zero_count
0  1  2  3               3               0           1
1 -1 -1  1               1               2           0
2  0  0  0               0               0           5
```

Anyone knows what might be going wrong, or could help me find the best way to do what I'm looking for?

Thank you.

Comment: You assign `'positive_count'` and `'negative_count'` first, so those get 0s added and then you wind up summing those too in `'zero_count'`

Comment: @ALollz good point out, can't believe I overlooked something so trivial

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some ways, but one option is using `np.sign` and `get_dummies`:

```
u = (pd.get_dummies(np.sign(df.stack()))
       .sum(level=0)
       .rename({-1: 'negative_count', 1: 'positive_count', 0: 'zero_count'}, axis=1))
u

   negative_count  zero_count  positive_count
0               0           0               3
1               2           0               1
2               0           3               0

df = pd.concat([df, u], axis=1)
df

   A  B  C  negative_count  zero_count  positive_count
0  1  2  3               0           0               3
1 -1 -1  1               2           0               1
2  0  0  0               0           3               0
```

`np.sign` treats zero differently from positive and negative values, so it is ideal to use here.

---

Another option is `groupby` and `value_counts`:

```
(np.sign(df)
   .stack()
   .groupby(level=0)
   .value_counts()
   .unstack(1, fill_value=0)
   .rename({-1: 'negative_count', 1: 'positive_count', 0: 'zero_count'}, axis=1))

   negative_count  zero_count  positive_count
0               0           0               3
1               2           0               1
2               0           3               0
```

Slightly more verbose but still worth knowing about.

Comment: Thank you! @ALollz pointed out what I was doing wrong, but I'm gonna try these as well to see which option is more efficient, since I plan to apply it on a big dataset.

Comment: @coldspped I want to apply it to a big dataset, so if you need a more efficient version I would be greateful to know!

Comment: @Jack `sign` is fast, but `stack` and `unstack` are generally on the slower side. Nothing is slower than `apply`, though. If it is too slow, let me know. Because coming up with a faster solution will involve a lot of effort I'm not going to invest unless you can confirm there are issues with what has been presented :)

Comment: Im done testing all the options, `sign` was almost twice as fast than `value_counts`, both of them were way faster than apply and worked great :D